# Same resolution in Android Studio and my Device but different looks

Tags: java, android, user-interface, kotlin

I am currently programming an Android app and using Kotlin and Android 7, but when I run the app on my phone the picture is a bit different than when I design it in UI Designer. I have chosen the same resolution for both and I am stumped because I have had little contact with the frontend so far. Hopefully someone can help me, thanks already!

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="194.3dp"
        android:layout_height="144.3dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="83dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="583.7dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="82.7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gui_base"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        android:contentDescription="GUI" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="47dp"
        android:layout_height="53.3dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="161.3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="648dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="151.7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="78.7dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/homebutton"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        android:contentDescription="HomeButton" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhXTZ.png)
 [|||  My Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5nMh.png)

Comment: Hey man, Stackoverflow is for help with the codding , so if you post more details of your issue we can help, post your XML code, Screenshots of the Ui in the designer and on device , and then we can have look at it

Comment: Hey @RubenMeiring I have edited now my Question

Comment: I am assuming the problem is the sizes of the images and the  "Play" sign moving a bit up, I would suggest adding these to your image view, this will make it so the image with  scales with the resolution of the screen

  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
           android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: What exactly is different? I can't see any differences

Comment: I would also suggest putting the image views into thier own layout , so the become one entity but you can still use them individualy,

Comment: @iknow The images change size and the play button is moved

Comment: Which Layout would u suggest @RubenMeiring?

Comment: @Juferdinand  check iknows answer actually his solution is much cleaner than mine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageBackground"
        android:layout_width="194.3dp"
        android:layout_height="144.3dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageFront"
        android:layout_width="47dp"
        android:layout_height="53.3dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageBackground"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageBackground"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageBackground"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageBackground"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now You can paste this to another container. And the **Result:**

[image]

It will always center the button. If You want the center image (play button) to be a little lower You can add bias `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.75"`. Now the center image will be at 1/4 hight from the bottom.

---

*But I think You should newer hardcode margins to place somewhere on the screen. E.g. You have added `android:layout_marginTop="583.7dp"` this will only work on one screen resolution and on every other it will look bad. If You want it to be on the bottom just set the bottom constraint to the bottom of the parent and add a 16dp margin.*